# show that $V = \text{ker}(f) \oplus \text{im}(f)$ when $f^2 = f$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

If $f$ is an endomorphism of $V$, and $f^2 = f$, show that $V = \text{ker}(f) \oplus \text{im}(f)$

My answer:

$$
f(v) = w \in \text{im}(f)\\
f(f(v)) = f(w) = w
$$

Then we know that every element that is in our image it's not in our kernel, hence:
$$
\text{ker}(f) \cap \text{im}(f) = \left\{0\right\}
$$
Then:
$$
V = \text{ker}(f) \oplus \text{im}(f)
$$

I don't know if wasn't rigorous enough or I'm wrong... Please correct me if I'm wrong! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So far, you've only shown that $K := \ker(f)$ and $I:= \text{Im}(f)$ were in direct sum, not that their sum makes up for the all space $V$, i.e. $V = K + I$.

**Hint:** Let $v \in V$. Then write $v = v - f(v) + f(v)$ and conclude!

> *Note:* A mapping $p : V \rightarrow V$ s.t. $p^2 = p$ is called a **projection**.